# Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229)

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to set up VSCode to debug an npm script.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch via NPM",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "test"],
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason:
>   Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9229).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot debug in visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292932/cannot-debug-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 2):

There's a known bug in 2.0.1-beta.31 for node functions. Please try adding `"NODE_OPTIONS": "--inspect=5858"` to your local.settings.json file as a workaround.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is simply change, on visual studio interface, at play icon .. run with  (IIS Express in VS 2017).... And select a different browser .. probably one which you are not using.

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by Visual Studio's JavaScript debugger. You can turn it off in `Main menu > Options > Debugging > General > Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error vanished if I made sure that all Chrome windows are closed before I hit the **Play** button in Visual Studio - the hint came from [Cannot debug in visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292932/cannot-debug-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't for everybody, but worth a check.  I had a heck of a time understanding my ECONNREFUSED error.

Apparently VS_code in debug mode doesn't play nice with any script that contains `nodemon`, and that makes sense once you start thinking about it.. Check your package.json and adjust accordingly.

I was playing with [simple-react-full-stack](https://github.com/crsandeep/simple-react-full-stack) template which includes the script `"server": "nodemon src/server/index.js"`.